# CRM 2013: Javascript to cancel a Task does not work when the record is opened from Advanced Find

Tags: javascript, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

We are on CRM 2013. The requirement is to get rid of the 'Close' button completely from the Task form, and then create a new button 'Cancel' to cancel the Task. So when clicking on this button, the Task will be 'Save as Cancelled'.

So we followed a blog by Guru Prasad about changing record using javascript: http://guruprasadcrm.blogspot.com/2013/02/change-record-status-using-javascript.html

The script is working fine. When the 'Cancel' button is clicked, then it will change status to cancelled.

I also included this line of code before the SOAP request in case if the page is modified before the request to cancel is sent.

```
Xrm.Page.data.entity.save("saveandclose");
```

However we found a very weird bug that for some reason the script is not triggered when the record is opened from Advanced Find. It is as if the page gets closed immediately when clicking this new custom Cancel button.

Do you know if there's any differences between running scripts on records opened from Advanced Find vs. regular?

Here is the javascript to change record status:

```
    function changeRecordStatus(RECORD_ID, stateCode, statusCode) {

    //first of all save all data before sending the request, in case if there are some data that hasn't been saved
    Xrm.Page.data.entity.save("saveandclose");

    // create the SetState request
    var request = "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">";
    request += "<s:Body>";
    request += "<Execute xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">";
    request += "<request i:type=\"b:SetStateRequest\" xmlns:a=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts\" xmlns:b=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2011/Contracts\">";
    request += "<a:Parameters xmlns:c=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic\">";
    request += "<a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
    request += "<c:key>EntityMoniker</c:key>";
    request += "<c:value i:type=\"a:EntityReference\">";
    request += "<a:Id>" + RECORD_ID + "</a:Id>";
    request += "<a:LogicalName>task</a:LogicalName>";
    request += "<a:Name i:nil=\"true\" />";
    request += "</c:value>";
    request += "</a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
    request += "<a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
    request += "<c:key>State</c:key>";
    request += "<c:value i:type=\"a:OptionSetValue\">";
    request += "<a:Value>" + stateCode + "</a:Value>";
    request += "</c:value>";
    request += "</a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
    request += "<a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
    request += "<c:key>Status</c:key>";
    request += "<c:value i:type=\"a:OptionSetValue\">";
    request += "<a:Value>" + statusCode + "</a:Value>";
    request += "</c:value>";
    request += "</a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
    request += "</a:Parameters>";
    request += "<a:RequestId i:nil=\"true\" />";
    request += "<a:RequestName>SetState</a:RequestName>";
    request += "</request>";
    request += "</Execute>";
    request += "</s:Body>";
    request += "</s:Envelope>";

    //send set state request
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: "xml",
        url: Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl() + "/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc/web",
        data: request,
        beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
            XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml, text/xml, */*");
            XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services/IOrganizationService/Execute");
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
            Xrm.Page.ui.close();
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

}

Then here is the command definition of the new custom ribbon button to cancel the Task. I passed in statuscode = 2 and statecode = 6 into the function above.

```
<CommandDefinitions>
      <CommandDefinition Id="Mscrm.SaveAsCancelled">
        <EnableRules>
          <EnableRule Id="Mscrm.VisualizationPaneNotMaximized" />
          <EnableRule Id="Mscrm.SaveAsCancelled.FormRule" />
        </EnableRules>
        <DisplayRules>
          <DisplayRule Id="Mscrm.CanWriteSelected" />
          <DisplayRule Id="Mscrm.SelectedEntityHasStatecode" />
        </DisplayRules>
        <Actions>
          <JavaScriptFunction FunctionName="changeRecordStatus" Library="$webresource:new_DeactivateTask.js">
            <CrmParameter Value="FirstPrimaryItemId" />
            <IntParameter Value="2" />
            <IntParameter Value="6" />
          </JavaScriptFunction>
        </Actions>
      </CommandDefinition>
```

Thanks, really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link is helping us tremendously. It's a new CRM 2013 feature:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481607.aspx